# Imacros IF = #EANF# MACroERROR

Tags: imacros

I'm using the below code to scrape names from twitter.

```
VERSION BUILD=11.5.499.3066
TAB T=1
TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS
SET !ERRORIGNORE NO
SET !LOOP 20
TAG POS=45 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:ProfileNameTruncated<SP>account-group EXTRACT=TXT
SET Name  EVAL("var extract  = \"{{!EXTRACT}}\"; if (extract == \"#EANF#\") MacroError(\"Value is not in the set range\";")

SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=* FILE=Names.csv
WAIT SECONDS=2
```

i'm getting this message Error -1250: JScript statement in EVAL contains the following error: Expected ',' or ')'. Line 7: SET Name  EVAL("var extract  = \"{{!EXTRACT}}\"; if (extract == \"#EANF#\") MacroError(\"Value is not in the set range\";")

i'm all new and the beginner.  Please help
Thanks

Comment: Just read the error message and add a bracket: `SET Name EVAL("var extract  = \"{{!EXTRACT}}\"; if (extract == \"#EANF#\") MacroError(\"Value is not in the set range\");")`

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to understand what are you actually want to achieve. Since ther us no TAG POS value loop so it will extract the same value always. Here is the edited code in javascript

```
     var macro; 
        macro =  "CODE:";
        macro +=  "VERSION BUILD=11.5.499.3066" + "\n";
        macro +=  "TAB T=1" + "\n";
        macro +=  "TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS" + "\n";
        macro +=  "SET !ERRORIGNORE NO" + "\n";
        macro +=  "SET !LOOP {{i}}" + "\n";
        macro +=  "TAG POS={{!LOOP}} TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:ProfileNameTruncated<SP>account-group EXTRACT=TXT" + "\n";

    var savemacro; 
        savemacro =  "CODE:";
        savemacro +=  "SET !EXTRACT {{tname}}" + "\n";
        savemacro +=  "SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=* FILE=Names.csv" + "\n";
        savemacro +=  "WAIT SECONDS=2" + "\n";


    for (i=1;i<=10000000; i++) {
     ret = iimSet("i", i);
    retcode = iimPlay(macro)
     var tname = iimGetLastExtract(1);
    if (tname == "#EANF#"){
     tname = "";
    }
ret = iimSet("tname", tname);
 iimPlay(savemacro)
}
```

Copy the code in notepad and save as *.js extension
This code will replace the #EANF# with nothing i.e. you will get the empty row. If the extracted value is #EANF#
Change the value of i to the number where the TAG POS start. Right now it's 1.